# In iOS6 how to get the IP address

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6

I use the following code. It works fine on iOS 5, but in iOS 6 I didn't get the IP address.

```
   #import <ifaddrs.h> 
   #import <arpa/inet.h>
  -(NSString *)getIPAddress {    
    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;
    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
    // Loop through linked list of interfaces
    temp_addr = interfaces;
    while(temp_addr != NULL) {
        if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
            // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
               if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr-    >ifa_name]isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                // Get NSString from C String

   address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];               
            }
        }
        temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
    }
}
   // Free memory
     freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;
  }
```

Is there any problem with WiFi connections in iOS 6? It works well in iOS 5. Thank you.

Comment: Please complete your code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *str =[self getIPAddress];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



-(NSString *)getIPAddress
{
struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
NSString *wifiAddress = nil;
NSString *cellAddress = nil;
NSString *addr;
if(!getifaddrs(&interfaces)) {
    temp_addr = interfaces;
    while(temp_addr != NULL) {
        sa_family_t sa_type = temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family;
        if(sa_type == AF_INET || sa_type == AF_INET6) {
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name];
           addr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];
                          if([name isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                                   wifiAddress = addr;
            } else
                if([name isEqualToString:@"pdp_ip0"]) {
                                          cellAddress = addr;
                }
        }
        temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
    }
    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
}
return addr;
}
```

Comment: i think this is infinite loop at the while even in ios 5 also it is not working

Comment: is it private or public .is this accepatable in applestore

Comment: it is public,I don't know clearly but it is  possible to accept applestore

Comment: sorry i don have enough reputations i will vot elater

Comment: thank u today  i voted to u for excellent answer one week back