# Get IP Address on iPhone | Objective-C or Swift

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ip, external, ip-address

I just found this code to get my iPhone's **IP Address** using `Objective-C` but it's kinda **slow** for the project I'm working on:

```
- (NSString*)getExternalIP{
NSString *externalIP = @"";
NSArray *ipItemsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
NSURL *iPURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dyndns.org/cgi-bin/check_ip.cgi"];
if (iPURL) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *theIpHtml = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:iPURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    if (!error){
        NSScanner *theScanner;
        NSString *text = nil;
        theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:theIpHtml];
        while ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
            [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<" intoString:NULL] ;
            [theScanner scanUpToString:@">" intoString:&text] ;
            theIpHtml = [theIpHtml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@>", text] withString:@" "] ;
            ipItemsArray = [theIpHtml componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
            int an_Integer= (int)[ipItemsArray indexOfObject:@"Address:"];
            externalIP =[ipItemsArray objectAtIndex: ++an_Integer];
        }
        return externalIP;
    }
}
return @"error";}
```

Do you know an alternative solution or a way to fix this one?
**NOTE**: it has to work on Wi-fi and cellular.

Thanks!

Comment: how about the [code found in this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15173291/in-ios6-how-to-get-the-ip-address)?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Just tried it and works great for cellular...still don't get why on Wi-fi retrieves 0.0.0.0 or an address which differs from the "external" one

Answer (score 3):

I am found ip address using this way. First you can import two library.

```
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

then after you can use this action

```
- (NSString *)getIPAddress {

    NSString *address = @"error";
    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;
    int success = 0;
    // retrieve the current interfaces - returns 0 on success
    success = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if (success == 0) {
        // Loop through linked list of interfaces
        temp_addr = interfaces;
        while(temp_addr != NULL) {
            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                // Check if interface is en0 which is the wifi connection on the iPhone
                if([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                    // Get NSString from C String
                    address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr)->sin_addr)];

                }

            }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }
    // Free memory
    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return address;

}
```

and call this action in your code like this way.

```
NSString *strYourIP = [self getIPAddress];
```

I hope this is use full to you....

Answer (score 0):

Before using the code in the question, think about this for a bit:

*What's going to happen if dyndns.org starts to lag?*

In my experience, the response time of this service varies so badly that it's downright unusable for anything which might be performance sensitive. (I had response times varying from 0 sec to 50+ sec, tested on multiple decent connections.) It would be much better to find / set up a service for this purpose which is more reliable. If you have control over a web service for the application you're working with, I think it's trivial to add. (In PHP, it's a one-liner.)